# Swift: startOfDay function returning 5:00 AM

Tags: swift, date

I am calling the startOfDay function on the current date but I am getting 05:00 instead of 00:00. Any input on why this is happening would be appreciated.

Code:

```
let date = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: Date())
print(date)
```

output:

```
2020-08-05 05:00:00 +0000
```

Comment: What timezone are you in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you're printing `Date` object directly it considers the time-zone. You can provide a date formatter to convert it.

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"
let date = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: Date())
let string = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
print(string)
```